# PVC/Metal Pipe Weight Capacity

Tags: plumbing, pipe

My daughter is in ballet, and we were going to make Do your own (DIY) Ballet Barre. Also my 10 year old son wants to do pull ups (or just hang his weight, he's around 100 pounds).

a) Just curious what is the weight capacity, if someone were to hang on this DIY ballet barre, before I start making this.

b) Additionally, would it be stable or shifty/wobbly?

I assume metal pipes will holder stronger than plastic/pvc.  These are pretty standard in the dance/industry, and lot of College students in the Arts do this.

See videos, and pictures below.

We plan to make Width: 3-4 ft wide

Height: 5 ft

**Resource:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZ12lLHg3BM

[image]

[image]

Comment: PVC is good for hanging clothes out of the laundry machine :)

Comment: Yeah I know @r13 so you know the weight capacity?

Comment: It can be calculated with fixed geometric parameters - frame width, height, and strength/grade of the pipe material. I afraid it is beyond the scope of this forum. Try to post the question on the "engineering forum", someone there may be glad to help.

Comment: Think I would go with steel pipe.  Usually stronger and would bend, PVC might break/crack with sharp edges/points if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PVC will be weak and wobbly.

I've built something similar using steel tubes and aluminium elbows and tees. That's pretty cheap and quite strong.

[image]

You can find the hardware online. These are sometimes used in retail to make [custom shelf structures](https://www.retif.eu/c-2582-urban/), and in exhibitions to build booths/stands.

Once the structure is built, you can make a small hole in the tube below the screw to keep it well centered so it doesn't turn, and add a drop of Loctite.

Steel plumbing pipes may also be cheaper. It depends on what diameter of tube  you need, and that depends on the size of the user's hand.

Note if you want a pullup bar, and you have a corridor, you can use a tube and two of these:

[image]

Comment: A bar for a 10-year-old might be a tad low for the adults to walk by, if mounted permanently. You might consider two wall-plates, one with a circular hole in the centre, the other start with a hole then saw it out to a U-shape. Bar can be inserted into the hole then dropped into the U. Won't come out again until you reverse that action. Once the bar is removed, the plates [though a bit unsightly] won't be in the way of anyone wanting to walk past.